# AutoMapper "Member not found" with UseDestinationValue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper-3

I am trying to use AutoMapper to map a ViewModel to a Model.

Here is my simplified ViewModel (the source) class:

```
    public class EditPaypointVM
    {

        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        public Int64 OrganisationId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string OrganisationContactNumber { get; set; }

        public Int64 PostalAddressId { get; set; }

        public string PostalAddressAddressText { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int64 PostalAddressArea { get; set; }

        public string PostalAddressAreaText { get; set; }

        public string PostalAddressCode { get; set; } 

        public Int64 PhysicalAddressId { get; set; }

        public string PhysicalAddressAddressText { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Int64 PhysicalAddressArea { get; set; }

        public string PhysicalAddressAreaText { get; set; }

        public string PhysicalAddressCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my simplified Model (destination) class:

```
    public class Paypoint
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

        public virtual Employer Employer { get; set; }

        public virtual List<EmploymentContract> EmploymentContracts { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }


    public class Organisation
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<EmailAddress> EmailAdresses { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ContactNumber> ContactNumbers { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Address> Adresses { get; set; }

        public string RegisteredName { get; set; }

        public string TradingName { get; set; }

        public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

        public string WebsiteAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code I execute to create mappings in memory on application start:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<EditPaypointVM, Paypoint>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.IsActive,
                opt => opt.UseValue(true))
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Organisation,
                opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
           .Ignore(i => i.Employer)
           .Ignore(i => i.EmploymentContracts);
```

Upon executing 'AssertConfigurationIsvalid' within a unit test, an "Unmapped  error is thrown which states that the Organisation member of Paypoint is unmapped.

Any ideas on what causes this?

Comment: What is the type of `Organisation`? By the way in order to the AssertConfigurationIsvalid work you need to Ignore your property with `.Ignore(i => i.Organisation)`

Comment: Or you need to write: `.ForMember(dest => dest.Organisation, opt =>
                      {
                          opt.MapFrom(src => src.Organisation);
                          opt.UseDestinationValue();
                      });` to make the `AssertConfigurationIsvalid` happy

Comment: @nemesv Organisation is a complex type which contains collections of other complex types like Addresses.  Some of the internal properties of Organisation needs to be set and that is why I applied 'UseDestinationValue'.

Comment: @nemesv The source class, `EditPaypointVM` has been flattened and does not contain a single property which can be mapped to `Organisation`.  Rather it just has properties which maps to attributes of organisation.  So `.ForMember(dest => dest.Organisation, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.Organisation); opt.UseDestinationValue(); });` does not compile.

Comment: The `.ForMember(dest => dest.Organisation, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.Organisation); opt.UseDestinationValue(); });` should compile... what is the error message? Which version of Automapper are you using?

Comment: The error is "'EditPaypointVM' does not contain a definition for 'Organisation'"...  I am using version 3.2.1

Comment: @nemesv I added the code for the two classes to more clearly illustrate why this code throws an error.  Why is it necessary to call `.Ignore(i => i.Organisation)` in order for `AssertConfigurationIsvalid` to work?  Is there a known issue with `UseDestinationValue`?  I could not find anything in this regard on their github page.